# Right encoding to send data

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

Some things that were trivial in Python 2 get a bit more tedious in Python 3. I am sending a string followed by some hex value:

```
buffer = "ABCD"
buffer += "\xCA\xFE\xCA\xFE"
```

This gives an error when sending, and I have read in other post that the solution is to use `sendall` and `encode`:

```
s.sendall(buffer.encode("UTF-8"))
```

However, what is send in the network for the hex value is the UTF-8 encoded:

```
c3 8a c3 be c3 8a c3 be
```

instead of the exact bytes I defined. How should I do this without using external libraries and possibly without having to "convert" the data into another structure?

I know this question has been widely asked, but I can't find a satisfying solution

Comment: No, I already tried and Python complains saying the string has no enconding

Comment: I cannot inline all my data like this, and when I try to concatenate I get a `can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str`. Python 3 seems to overcomplicate things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information in your question, you *might* be able to get away with encoding your data as latin-1, because this will not change any byte values

```
buffer = "ABCD"
buffer += "\xCA\xFE\xCA\xFE"

payload = buffer.encode("latin-1")
print(payload)
b'ABCD\xca\xfe\xca\xfe'
```

On the other side, you could just decode from latin-1:

```
buffer = payload.decode('latin-1')
buffer
'ABCDÊþÊþ'
```

But you might prefer to keep the text and binary parts of your message as their respective types:

```
encoded_text = payload[:4]
encoded_text
b'ABCD'
text = encoded_text.decode('latin-1')
print(text)
ABCD
binary_data = payload[4:]
binary_data
b'\xca\xfe\xca\xfe'
```

If your text contains codepoints which cannot be encoded as latin-1 - '你好，世界' for example - you could follow the same approach, but you would need to encode the text as UTF-8 while encoding the binary data as 'latin-1'; the resulting bytes will need to be split into their text and binary sections and decoded separately.

Finally: encoding string literals like `'\xca\xfe\xca\xfe'` is a poor style in Python3 - better to declare them as bytes literals like `b'\xca\xfe\xca\xfe'`.

Comment: "latin-1", although it seems like a "hack", worked great for my situation. I also liked your comment about keeping text and binary parts as their respective types.

Comment: There's a reason why latin-1 is the "default" encoding on the web ;-)  More seriously: Python3 is much stricter about the distinction between text and binary data, so separating the types is good practice.  It takes some getting used to after Python2's freewheeling approach, but leads to better code in the end I find.

Comment: I totally agree and I think it was a good move by Python 3, as @jlandercy implied. But, at the same time, I feel that Python success came like PHP success and others: because it was easy and simple. I hope the language doesn't develop into something as strict and cumbersome as Java, because it was one of Python's advantages

Answer (score 2):

You may think Python 3 is making thing more difficult, but it is the converse which is intended. You are experiencing a charset enforcement issue. In python 2 there were multiple reasons to be confused with UTF-8 and Unicode charsets. It is now fixed.

First of all, if you need to send binary data, you better choose the ad-hoc type, which is `bytes`. Using Python 3, it is sufficient to prefix your string with a `b`. This should fix you problem:

```
buffer = b"ABCD"
buffer += b"\xCA\xFE\xCA\xFE"
s.sendall(buffer)
```

Of course, `bytes` object has no `encode` method as it is already encoded to binary. But it has the converse method `decode`.

When you create a `str` object using quotes with no prefix, by default Python 3 will use **Unicode** encoding (which was enforced by `unicode` type or `u` prefix in Python 2). It means you will require to use `encode` method to get binary data.

Instead, directly use `bytes` to store binary data as no encoding operation will occur and it will stay as you typed it.

The error `can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str` speaks for itself. Python is complaining it cannot concatenate `str` with `bytes` as the former data requires a further step, namely encoding, to make the `+` operation meaningful.